# Builds with command line "devenv" but not with Visual Studio (sln) and MSBUild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild, teamcity, devenv

I'm trying to set up a project with TeamCity and I was wondering what does exactly happen when I choose “Visual Studio (sln)” from the drop down menu under "Runner Type". When I choose this option my project fails to build and I get a bunch of compilation errors like this :

> Logging\LoggingSingleton.cpp(19, 0): error C1083: Cannot open include
>   file: 'Auto/AutoHandle.h': No such file or directory 
>   d:\tcbuildagent\work\b1f06d91677fef59\consumer_2011_050\coretech\sdk\src\auto\AutoTempFile.h(16,
>   0): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Coretech.h': No such file
>   or directory
>   d:\tcbuildagent\work\b1f06d91677fef59\consumer_2011_050\coretech\sdk\src\auto\AutoTempFolder.h(23,
>   0): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Coretech.h': No such file
>   or directory
>   d:\tcbuildagent\work\b1f06d91677fef59\consumer_2011_050\coretech\sdk\src\logging\McLog2.h(8,
>   0): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Coretech.h': No such file
>   or directory
>   d:\tcbuildagent\work\b1f06d91677fef59\consumer_2011_050\coretech\sdk\src\encryption\McAfeeObfuscation.h(2,
>   0): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Coretech.h': No such file
>   or directory
>   d:\tcbuildagent\work\b1f06d91677fef59\consumer_2011_050\coretech\sdk\src\file\BaseIniReader.h(21,
>   0): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Coretech.h': No such file
>   or directory
>   d:\tcbuildagent\work\b1f06d91677fef59\consumer_2011_050\coretech\sdk\src\file\IniReader.h(21,
>   0): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Coretech.h': No such file
>   or directory
>   d:\tcbuildagent\work\b1f06d91677fef59\consumer_2011_050\coretech\sdk\src\file\BaseIniReader.h(21,
>   0): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Coretech.h': No such file
>   or directory
>   d:\tcbuildagent\work\b1f06d91677fef59\consumer_2011_050\coretech\sdk\src\file\BaseIniReader.h(21,
>   0): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Coretech.h': No such file
>   or directory

However, if I choose “Command Line” as my runner type, and run my solution like : ***devenv ………../LogReader.sln /Build “Debug”***  it builds fine with no compilation error. But we don’t want our teams to manually put in the parameters every time, and either build it with MSBuild (gives same errors as Visual Studio sln) or “Visual Studio (sln)”.

Comment: Does the build passes when you build the sln manually via msbuild on the server?

Answer (score 1):

You might verify the platform that it is building with, or specify it.  We've had similar issues in the past when the project settings were inconsistent across platform, and the platform being built was not the one that was expected.  In this case, I would suspect that one platform does not have the same include directories as another.

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity is a build server which has a set of plugin support to perform the more than one type of build process in a very smoother fashion. TeamCity downloads the code from the Source Control application to a working folder and starts the build process. The build process expects the assembly references and libraries as similar to a developer machine. For example,  a basic .net application requies the appropriate .net framework to perform the build process. Similarly in your case, the libraries. If you can make the library files available, the build process will run without an issue.